# Автоматическое воспроизведение команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Имеется следующий код:

```
@client.command()

async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Succes!")
```

Помогите и объясните как автоматизировать эту команду, чтобы она воспроизводилась каждые, например, 30 секунд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/tasks/index.html)

Стандартный пример из документации:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.index = 0
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
```